# Delete files older than certain days that not have certain substring in name (Linux)

Tags: linux, terminal, grep, cron, find

I have a folder with backup files with names like:

```
backup_2017_12_01__09_00_01.sql.gz
backup_2017_12_01__10_00_01.sql.gz
...
backup_2017_12_01__19_00_01.sql.gz
backup_2017_12_01__20_00_01.sql.gz

backup_2017_12_02__09_00_01.sql.gz
backup_2017_12_02__10_00_01.sql.gz
...
backup_2017_12_02__19_00_01.sql.gz
backup_2017_12_02__20_00_01.sql.gz
```

and so on.

I have a cron that should perform the deletion of the files respecting these rules:

1. delete all files older than 45 days; solved with `find. -mtime +45 -exec rm {} \;`
2. delete all files older than 7 days except those with the string `__20_` in the name (the last backup in the evening); a command that is based on the last modification time rather than the name would also be fine

Can someone help me on the second point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With **`find`**'s `-name` test:

```
find . -type f -name "*.gz" ! -name "*__20_*.gz" -mtime +7 -delete
```

Comment: Thank you! The solution you propose, however, takes all the files, I need those modified for more than 7 days, so it should be changed like this: `find . -type f -name "* .gz"! -name "* __ 20 _ *. gz" -mtime +7 -delete`

Comment: @mimet, of course, just missed that option. Updated

Answer (score 0):

```
find /p/a/t/h \( -mtime +45 -o \( -mtime +5 ! -name '*__20_*' \) \) -delete
```

If you want, you can be more explicit:

```
find /p/a/t/h \( -mtime +45 -o \( -mtime +5 -and ! -name '*__20_*' \) \) -delete
```

Note that you should be more precise with language.  This does not delete files that are "older than 45 days".  It deletes files based on their modification time, which can be very different than age.

Comment: Perfect! The second solution is perfect for my case, it also includes the first point of my question. You're right, I was wrong indicating "creation" I meant "change". Thanks so much!

Comment: Be careful with "change", too!  'ctime' is the 'change time' which has nothing to do with the time the contents of the file were changed, but refers to the time of the last change to the file's metadata.  Probably a bigger mistake than misspelling 'create', but that's just my opinion.

Comment: I'm very bad :(
I meant _"modification date"_, so **mtime** is fine for me (I have a little better understanding the differences reading [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-mtime-atime-and-ctime), so I hope not to fall into these inaccuracies anymore). Thank you!